# How to optimize collections creating by numerical switch?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a certain number of objects based on user-selected drop-down list. Now I have this code.

```
var driversFunc = function () {

var driversCount = osagoViewModel.fields.driversCount.selectedValue();

switch (driversCount) {

    case "many":
        return [];
    case "1":
        return [new driver()];
    case "2":
        return [new driver(), new driver()];
    case "3":
        return [new driver(), new driver(), new driver()];
    case "4":
        return [new driver(), new driver(), new driver(), new driver()];
    case "5":
        return [new driver(), new driver(), new driver(), new driver(), new driver()];
    }
};
```

(knockout.js is used)

Comment: This reminds me of some Daily WTF entries... :D

Comment: Untagged knockout as the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your switch might be able to be replaced with:

```
if (driversCount === "many") {
  return [];
} else {
  var count = parseInt(driversCount, 10);
  var l = [];
  while (count--) l.push(new driver());
  return l;
}
```

I don't understand why `many` maps to `[]`.

Comment: because the first rule can not take into account the large number and therefore apply different instructions

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the context but your code can be rewritten using for loop:

```
var driversFunc = function () {
    var driversCount = osagoViewModel.fields.driversCount.selectedValue();
    var result = [];
    if (driversCount != "many") {
        for (var i = 0; i < (+driversCount || 0); i++) {
            result.push(new driver());
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return Number(driversCount) 
        ? ( function add(i){ 
             return i ? add(i-1).concat(new driver) : [] 
            }(driversCount) 
           )
        : [];
```

Alternatively<sup>**1**</sup>

```
return Number(driversCount) 
        ? String(new Array(driversCount))
          .split(',')
          .map(function(){return new driver})
        : [];
```

<sup>**1**</sup> the `String(new Array([n])).split ...` syntax is a small trick to force  application of the `map` method (`new Array([n]).map(...)` won't work).

Comment: For `driversCount = "4"` it gives 5 `new driver`s. Otherwise it's awesome :)